# Webpack ProvidePlugin global variable (Cannot find module)

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm pretty new to Webpack, but can't figure out why my ProvidePlugin call is not working as expected.

I have the following file:

### App.js

```js
var App = function() {
    getSomething: function(size) {}
}();

module.exports = App;
```

I want this 'App' variable to be globally accessible because other files use it like this:

### Layout.js

```js
var Layout = function () {
    App.getSomething('md');
}();
```

### webpack.config.js

In webpack.config.js I have the following line:

```js
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ App: 'app' })
```

This is my entry:

```js
entry: {
    'app': './angularApp/metronicapp.ts',
}
```

### metronicapp.ts

```js
import './metronic/global/scripts/app';
```

Where `app` is my `app.js` which is displayed above.

I get the following error in the browser: 
**`Cannot find module "app"`**

And when I compile webpack in the console:
**`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'app'`**

I can't figure what I'm missing. Is my app.js not in the correct format? Why is `App` still not available globally?

Comment: In your metronicapp.ts you are not importing the app. In App JS you could try changing the module.export to export default App. Or in the metronicapp.ts change the import to "import App from './metronic/global/scripts/app' " I'm new to this also, but that is what I would try.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### webpack.config.js

`ProvidePlugin` needs the path to your global module `App.js`.

```
const path = require('path');
...
plugins: [
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    App: path.resolve(__dirname, './path_to_App.js')
  })
]
```

#### global.d.ts

For Typescript not to complain about undefined constructs create 
`global.d.ts`

```
declare var App: any;
```

#### metronicapp.ts

No need to import `./metronic/global/scripts/app` inside `metronicapp.ts`, webpack will resolve `App` on build.

```
App.getSomething('foo');
```

#### Layout.js

```
var Layout = function() {
  App.getSomething('md');
}();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! All I had to add to make it work were the following lines:

module: {
    rules: [
    {
        test: require.resolve(path.join(ROOT, 'angularApp/metronic/global/scripts/metronic-app.js')),
        use: ['exports-loader?App']
    }]
}

Comment: Pointing to the path fails catastrophically for me.