# Access TypeScript global variables with webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack

I'm new to webpack and am in the process of converting a medium sized TypeScript app (without framework) over to using it. I have some global variables in my `main.ts` file that I can't access.

```
// Global variables
let templates;
let router;
let config;

$(document).ready(() => {
    $.get("/config", (data) => {

        // Create our config object
        config = new Config(data);

        // Load all templates
        templates = new Templates();

        templates.ready(() => {
            router = new Router();
            router.initialize();
        });
    }
}
```

When I try and access, say, `templates`, from the `Router` class, it is undefined.
I have `declare var templates` in my `Router.ts` file. I tried the suggestions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40416826) & [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47701378/webpack-provideplugin-global-variable-cannot-find-module) (putting them in a `globals.ts`/`globals.js` file, and using `ProvidePlugin` but without success)

webpack.config.js -

```
plugins: [
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            globals: path.resolve(__dirname, "./globals"),
        }),
    ],
```

main.ts -

```
$(document).ready(() => {
        $.get("/config", (data) => {

            // Create our config object
            globals.config = new Config(data);

            // Load all templates
            globals.templates = new Templates();

            globals.templates.ready(() => {
                globals.router = new Router();
                globals.router.initialize();
            });
        }
    }
```

globals.ts/js -

```
export let templates, pageManager, config;
```

I get the error `TS2304: Cannot find name 'globals'.`

If I then add in `import * as globals from "./globals"` it compiles but I get the following error in the browser console - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property config of #<Object> which has only a getter`

I'm a little lost at the moment. What's the best way to access these global objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your application as a Node.js one and then use WebPack to create a bundle.

Here's a simple example. I assume all input files are in one directory.
`webpack`, `webpack-cli`, `ts-loader`, `typescript` packages should be installed.

globals.ts

```
export let foo = null;
export let bar = null;
```

index.ts

```
import * as globals from "./globals";

globals.foo = "foo";
globals.bar = "bar";

console.log(globals);
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "esnext",
      "module": "commonjs"
   }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
let path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./index.ts",
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.tsx?$/,
          use: "ts-loader",
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }
      ]
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "scripts"),
      filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    mode: "development"
};
```